# Работа TID c MVCC PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

возникло недопонимание теории о внутренней работе PostgreSQL.

Индексные строки в PSQL ссылаются на строки таблицы при помощи TID (Tuple Idenfier), который состоит из номера блока и расположение строки в нем (смещение относительно начала страницы). Если произошло обновление строки при помощи механизма Heap Only Tuple (HOT), то TID может ссылаться на несколько версий одной строки (в рамках работы  MVCC).

Вопрос в следующем, **как работа TID пересекается с массивом указателей на версии строк, который хранится внутри страницы heap-файла отношения?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TID - это номер блока данных (это верно), но второй компонент не прямое смещение данных в этом блоке, а индекс массива line pointer (item pointer). Это отдельный массив на странице данных, который уже хранит действительные адреса таплов на этой странице.

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_16_1/src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT

> the index points to line pointer 1, and tuple 1 is
> marked as HEAP_HOT_UPDATED.  Tuple 2 is a HOT tuple, meaning it has
> no index entry pointing to it, and is marked as HEAP_ONLY_TUPLE.
> Although tuple 2 is not directly referenced by the index, it can still be
> found by an index search: after traversing from the index to tuple 1,
> the index search proceeds forward to child tuples as long as it sees the
> HEAP_HOT_UPDATED flag set.  Since we restrict the HOT chain to lie within
> a single page, this requires no additional page fetches and doesn't
> introduce much performance penalty.

Index scan приходящий с конкретным TID в блок данных находит что этот тапл отмечен флагом HEAP_HOT_UPDATED, после чего ищет на этой странице данных другие версии этой строки.

Вот тут ещё хороший материал есть по внутрянкам: http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql07/01.html